# Web Configuration Transformation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, command-line, web-config

Here’s a way to use the standalone Web Configuration Transformation Tool to use the same modifications that Visual Studio’s Configuration Manager uses to implement multiple deployment environments. In this example, I'm doing the transform of the connection string for deployment to a cloud platform. (The excellent UhuruCloud, for this example.)

My need was that I was trying to perform a VS Config Transform, but didn't need One-Click deployment support. My cloud host supplies a plugin for managing deployment, so I couldn't use Visual Studio's One-Click deployer which runs it for you, without showing exactly how it is executed. But VS is handy creating the transform files, so I wanted to take advantage of that.

**Use Visual Studio to create your transform template.**
  1. In VS, choose Build - Configuration Manager - New... and name it UhuruCloud, for example.
  2. In Solution Explorer, right-click on your Web.Config file and choose 'Add Config Transforms'
  3. Edit the resulting Web.UhuruCloud.config for the transform.

**Use the standalone Config Transform standalone Tool.**
Get the tool from http://ctt.codeplex.com/Wikipage?ProjectName=ctt
The syntax of the tool is like so:

```
ctt.exe s:source.config t:transform.config d:destination.config
```

**Use the standalone Config Transform standalone Tool.**
Get the tool from http://ctt.codeplex.com/Wikipage?ProjectName=ctt
The syntax of the tool is like so:

```
ctt.exe s:source.config t:transform.config d:destination.config
```

That’s just the most basic usage. Other good Examples are provided in the   distribution. For me, it was handy to have a quick batch script to make that call easier. Especially while trying to get the paths just right.

```
File: ctt_run.bat
@ECHO off
rem ... Use the Config Transform standalone Tool (CTT),  
rem ... from http://ctt.codeplex.com/Wikipage?ProjectName=ctt
rem ... Basic CTT syntax is "ctt.exe s:source.config t:transf.config d:dest.config"
rem ... Set the (S)ource, (T)ransformTemplate, and (D)estination files here.
SET S=C:\tfs-hill\MvcITunes1\MvcITunes1\Web.config
SET T=C:\tfs-hill\MvcITunes1\MvcITunes1\Web.UhuruCloud.config
SET D=Web.New.config
@ECHO on
C:\Common\ctt.exe s:%S% t:%T% d:%D%
```

That’s it. (My example writes the transformed file Web.New.config.)
I hope this is helpful to someone trying to perform a VS Config Transformation but doesn't need One-Click deployment support.

Comment: i dont suppose anyone has created a cSharp wrapper class so this .exe can be called from code and return success or fail messages?